# InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender - GAE - domain not managed by google apps

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I have an running application on GAE ( python ) .

Using the gae email api to send emails. ( mail.send_mail ).

Received the following error: InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender .

I would like the sender to be from my domain ( hello@mydomain.com ) . But the domain/email address' are not managed by Google Apps, though ( domain by a different registrar and email by a different MX provider).

Will I still be able to use the gae api to send emails (say, through email verification / domain verification just like what Amazon SES does ? ).

Answer (score 0):

Refer these links for using Amazon SES on GAE

http://www.radomirml.com/blog/2012/07/31/amazon-ses-service-with-java-on-gae/

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/HaloXUDEKBc

Comment: To clarify - this is not about sending through Amazon SES, but sending email through the GAE email api with an authorized sender.